# How to show data Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

This is my script code in Laravel:

```
<?php
$surat_masuk = DB::table('app_suratmasuk')->where('disposisi','like','%**{{ Session::get('fid') }}**%')->count(); 
?>

<span class="notif-alert ">{{ $surat_masuk }}</span>
```

I know , I have a mistake when adding `{{ Session::get('fid') }}`. I want to ask, how to write that code to show `{{ Session::get('fid') }}` because this script is in PHP syntax under PHP script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
$surat_masuk = DB::table('app_suratmasuk')
     ->where('disposisi','like', '%' . Session::get('fid') . '%')->count();
```